# Pushing process to background causes high kswapd0

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ethereum

I have a cpu-intensive process running on a raspberry pi that's executed by running a nodejs file. Running the first command (below) and then running the file on another tab works just fine. However when I run the process via a bash shell script, the process stalls.

Looking at the processes using `top` I see that `kswapd0` and `kworker/2:1+` takes over most of the cpu. What could be causing this?

FYI, the first command begins the Ethereum discovery protocol via HTTP and IPC

```
geth --datadir $NODE --syncmode 'full' --port 8080 --rpc --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 30310 --rpcapi 'personal,eth,net,web3,miner,txpool,admin,debug' --networkid 777 --allow-insecure-unlock --unlock "$HOME_ADDRESS" --password ./password.txt --mine --maxpeers 100 2> results/log.txt &


sleep 10

# create storage contract and output result
node performanceContract.js
```

UPDATE:
performanceContract.js

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
const fs = require('fs')
const provider = new ethers.providers.IpcProvider('./node2/geth.ipc')
const walletJson = fs.readFileSync('./node2/keystore/keys', 'utf8')
const pwd = fs.readFileSync('./password.txt', 'utf8').trim();
const PerformanceContract = require('./contracts/PerformanceContract.json');

(async function () {
    try {
        const wallet = await ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedJson(walletJson, pwd)
        const connectedWallet = wallet.connect(provider)
        const factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(PerformanceContract.abi, PerformanceContract.bytecode, connectedWallet)
        const contract = await factory.deploy()
        const deployedInstance = new ethers.Contract(contract.address, PerformanceContract.abi, connectedWallet);
        let tx = await deployedInstance.loop(6000)
        fs.writeFile(`./results/contract_result_xsmall_${new Date()}.txt`, JSON.stringify(tx, null, 4), () => {
            console.log('file written')
        })
...
```

Where loop is a method that loops keccak256 encryption method. It's purpose is to test diffent gas costs by alternating the loop #.

Comment: That smells like a memory leak, but without the js code it's really hard to tell

Comment: added my js code

Answer (score 0):

Solved by increasing the sleep time to 1min. Assume it was just a memory issue that need more time before executing the contract.